# Java: Gson: fromJson: Get element value

Tags: java, gson

I have a json string as:

```
string jsonString = "{"Header":{"ID": "103","DateTime": "2020-07-29 09:14:23.802-4:00 1","PlazaID": "01","Lane": "Lane 20","IPAddr": "192.9.0.123"},"Body": {"EventMsg": "Status: Online","EventNum": "99999"}}";
```

I am trying to get the value if ID from the above json by using Gson and it gives me NullPointerException. My code:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class );                                        
//System.out.println("jsonObject: " + jsonObject.toString());
String _ID = jsonObject.get("ID").getAsString();
```

I am not sure where the error in my code is. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
As per @Arvind's suggestion, I tried his code and am getting this error:

[image]

As per @Arvind's suggestion, this works:

```
String _ID = jsonObject.get("Header").getAsJsonObject().get("ID").getAsString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prettify your `jsonString` first for clarity:

```
{
  "Header": {
    "ID": "103",
    "DateTime": "2020-07-29 09:14:23.802-4:00 1",
    "PlazaID": "01",
    "Lane": "Lane 20",
    "IPAddr": "192.9.0.123"
  },
  "Body": {
    "EventMsg": "Status: Online",
    "EventNum": "99999"
  }
}
```

Notice that `"ID"` is inside `"Header"`, so you'd have to parse it this way:

```
String _ID = jsonObject.getJsonObject("Header").get("ID").getAsString();
```

Also, avoid using `get()` since there are better convenience methods:

```
String _ID = jsonObject.getJsonObject("Header").getString("ID");
```

Comment: What does the compiler say? (Edit your question and put it over there if it's too big)

Comment: I tried gson-2.8.6.jar and gson-2.6.2.jar and both are complaining that "get" method(the second get method) cannot be found in JsonElement.